# tLogCatcher not catching child job errors

Tags: talend

tLogCatcher is not catching errors coming from a child job.

When a job is run it'll show all of the error messages coming from a child job in the Run Window, but it is not catched by tLogCatcher to email.
If we don't loop the child job, tLogCatcher is catching all error messages and emailing. Is there another way to do this kind of loop, so tLogCather can the error message or is there something in my loop that I need to include?

This is a master job:
tjava--->tloop--->tJavaflex--->tJava--->tRunjob--->tjava

NOTE: tRunjob ***has Die on child error*** and Use an independent process to run subjob selected

This is a child job:
tPrejob--->tRestclient--->tjson--->tSetGlobalvar

NOTE: tRestclient and tJson have Die on error selected

Comment: I believe the problem maybe due to using an independent process to run the subjob. Try unchecking that option.

Comment: I've tried it without independent process and still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

We have a tLogCatcher in each and every one of our jobs as a way to catch all child errors the tLogCatcher itself is then linked to a logger Job.

Answer (score 0):

Even with tLogCather we will catch error like **Child job has failed to run**, but not exact error occured in child job.

To get the exact error occurred in child job.

**tRunJob---OnSubJobError--->tjava**

in tJava **`System.out.println(((String)globalMap.get("tRunJob_1_CHILD_EXCEPTION_STACKTRACE")));`**

then you can get exact error you got in child job.

I hope this will be helpful for you..!!!

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but it doesn't work.  From tRunJob, I didn't get an option for onSubJobError.  So, I've connected OnSubJobError from tLoop.  My loop will loop till 5 tries, but on the 6th try it doesn't kill the child job if not successful.  Would you have any sample job for my scenario?

Comment: You can simply use tRunJob---->Rightclickon tRunJob--->Onsubjob error